# SQL write NOT IN as FULL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Is it possible to write the following SQL statement as a FULL JOIN instead of using NOT IN?

```
select * from [user] u 
   AND u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM job)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT u.* FROM [user] u
FULL JOIN job uj ON u.user_id = uj.user_id
WHERE uj.user_id IS NULL
```

I'm looking to get all the users that do not have a record in the job table using a FULL JOIN.

Comment: Not using a FULL join, but a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN would work with the filter condition you specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select * 
from [user] u 
left join job uj
  on u.user_id = uj.user_id
where uj.user_id IS NULL
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the `user` regardless of whether or not there is a matching row in the `job` table.

Then when you add the `where j.user_id is null` filter it will return all the records only in the `user` table.

Here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that comes in handy when trying to figure out the proper join syntax.

See a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e832d/1) with both versions of the query (`NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN`) which shows that they both return the same data.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [user] u
LEFT JOIN job j on (u.user_id = j.user_id)
WHERE j.user_id is NULL
```

Why do you need to use FULL JOIN?  The above gives you what you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `left outer join`.  A `full outer join` is a bit redundant, because presumably `uj.user_id` would not be NULL.

The two queries are equivalent, although they might have different execution plans, depending on the database.